# How to retrieve WMS image from certain time/date

Tags: r, leaflet, wms

I'm trying to get de precipation radar data from the KNMI loaded in a leaflet in R. The data is located here: http://adaguc.knmi.nl/contents/webservices/WebServices_RADNL_OPER_R___25PCPRR_L3.html

So far, I've managed to get the current radar image to a leaflet layer with the following code:

```
require("leaflet")
require("dplyr")
 leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% 
  addWMSTiles(
    "http://geoservices.knmi.nl/cgi-bin/RADNL_OPER_R___25PCPRR_L3.cgi",
    layers = "RADNL_OPER_R___25PCPRR_L3_KNMI",
    options = WMSTileOptions(format = "image/png", transparent = TRUE),
    attribution = "KNMI"
  )
```

So far so good...

But what I really would like, is to get a radar image from a given timestamp. The series goes back to 2009 (see example from the KNMI viewer here: http://geoservices.knmi.nl/viewer2.0/?srs=EPSG%3A3857&bbox=-725.7203842048766,6500000,1220725.7203842048,7200000&service=http%3A%2F%2Fgeoservices.knmi.nl%2Fcgi-bin%2FRADNL_OPER_R___25PCPRR_L3.cgi%3F&layer=RADNL_OPER_R___25PCPRR_L3_COLOR%24image%2Fpng%24true%24default%241%240&selected=0&dims=time$current&baselayers=streetmap$world_line ).

On the web, I have found several examples of leaflet that supports dates/times, (like this: http://apps.socib.es/Leaflet.TimeDimension/examples/example14.html), but unfortunalety I lack the skills to convert this example to the R-version of leaflet.

Can this be done? Can I, for example, retrieve the precipation radar image from 2017-01-07T04:00? If yes: where would/could I start?

Or if it cannot be done with leaflet; any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was easier than expected ;-)

I just had to add a TIME-variable in the WMSTileOptions.

This works:

```
require("leaflet")
require("dplyr")
 leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% 
  addWMSTiles(
    "http://geoservices.knmi.nl/cgi-bin/RADNL_OPER_R___25PCPRR_L3.cgi",
    layers = "RADNL_OPER_R___25PCPRR_L3_COLOR",
    options = WMSTileOptions(format = "image/png", transparent = TRUE, TIME = "2017-01-07T04:00:00"),
    attribution = "KNMI neerslagradar"
  )
```